# Docker VotingApp build/release Jenkins on Kubernetes not idempotent

Tags: azure, docker, jenkins, kubernetes

I'm trying out deployments on Kubernetes via Jenkins with the Docker Voting App.  I use the Azure Container registry as a repository for the docker images.  On first try all is deployed ok:
[image]

When I re-run the pipeline without changing something I get the following error:
[image]

Redis service definition:

```html
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: redis
    version: alpine
  name: redis
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces//services/redis
spec:
  clusterIP: 
  ports:
  - name: 
    port: 6379
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 6379
  selector:
    app: redis
    version: alpine
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
---
```

The docker images are build with "latest" tag.

```html
stage 'Checkout'
node {
    git 'https://github.com/*****/example-voting-app.git' // Checks out example votiung app repository
   stage 'Docker Builds'
   docker.withRegistry('https://*****.azurecr.io', 'private-login') {
        parallel(
            "Build Worker App":{def myEnv = docker.build('*****.azurecr.io/example-voting-app-worker:latest', 'worker').push('latest')},
            "Build Result App":{def myEnv = docker.build('*****.azurecr.io/example-voting-app-result:latest', 'result').push('latest')},
            "Build Vote App":{def myEnv = docker.build('*****.azurecr.io/example-voting-app-vote:latest', 'vote').push('latest')}
            )
    }
    stage 'Kubernetes Deployment'
    sh 'kubectl apply -f kubernetes/basic-full-deployment.yml'
    sh 'kubectl delete pods -l app=vote'
    sh 'kubectl delete pods -l app=result'
    stage 'Smoke Test'
    sh 'kubectl get deployments'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your definition contains fields that are auto-generated/managed by the apiserver. Some of them are created at the time of object creation and can't be updated afterwards. **Remove** the following fields from your file to make it happy:

```
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces//services/redis
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```